# ShellTile add StandardTileData

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-phone-8

I want to add `StandardTileData` with image from the device which is in this path :

```
C:/Data/Users/DefApps/AppData/{4A3C6293-E51F-4B26-944A-88A2C3D028BE}/Local/Images/EHkozMIXZ8w.png
```

With this :

```
try
{
    string imageUrl = @"C:/Data/Users/DefApps/AppData/{4A3C6293-E51F-4B26-944A-88A2C3D028BE}/Local/Images/EHkozMIXZ8w.png";
    StandardTileData tileData = new StandardTileData();
    tileData.Title = videoItem.Name;
    tileData.BackBackgroundImage = new Uri(imageUrl);

    Uri mp = new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?" + "videoID=" + videoItem.idStr, UriKind.Relative);

    ShellTile.Create(mp, tileData, false);
}
catch { }
```

And i get this Exeption:

```
file:///C:/Data/Users/DefApps/AppData/{4A3C6293-E51F-4B26-944A-88A2C3D028BE}/Local/Images/EHkozMIXZ8w.png
```

Any idea why i get this error? Did i do something wrong?

Edit:

I tried this code :

```
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(videoItem.ImgUrl);

            var sri = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(videoItem.ImgUrl, UriKind.Relative));
            var data = sri.Stream;
            IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = storage.CreateFile("Shared\\ShellContent\\" + fileName))
            {
                data.CopyTo(stream);
            }

            StandardTileData tileData = new StandardTileData();
            tileData.Title = videoItem.Name;

            if (storage.FileExists("Shared\\ShellContent\\" + fileName))
            {
                tileData.BackgroundImage = new Uri(fileName, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            }

            Uri mp = new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?" + "videoID=" + videoItem.idStr, UriKind.Relative);

            ShellTile.Create(mp, tileData, true);
```

The debugger enter the `FileExists` method and the code work without exception. but i can't see the image on the tile.

Any idea why?

Solution:

The problem was that the `IsolatedStorageFileStream` and `data` needed to be closed:

```
stream.Close();
data.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you are using an image from IsolatedStorage it must be saved in Shared/ShellContent/
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.standardtiledata.backgroundimage%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) info:
`If the URI references an image that was stored in isolated storage, then the image must be in the Shared\ShellContent folder. For more information, see Data for Windows Phone.`

Copy your image to Shared/ShellContent and try like this:

```
StandardTileData tileData = new StandardTileData();
tileData.Title = videoItem.Name;
tileData.BackgroundImage = new Uri("/Shared/ShellContent/EHkozMIXZ8w.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
Uri mp = new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?" + "videoID=" + videoItem.idStr, UriKind.Relative);
ShellTile.Create(mp, tileData);
```

Comment: So what you suggest is to copy the image to this folder before?

Comment: @MTA Yes, SecondaryTiles can have images only from that folder. In my case that helped.

Comment: This path `/Shared/ShellContent/` exist in WP8 ?? how i can get the source of the path?

Comment: @MTA as it is said here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402541(v=vs.105).aspx - This folder is created when your app is installed... In my App, I've just created such a folder in VS, put image there and set is as content - it worked, but normally you can also put images there while your App is running.

Comment: Wrong - Uri should look like this: tileData.BackgroundImage = new Uri("/Shared/ShellContent/" + fileName, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) - that's what I think - check if it works

Comment: It's still create a blue tile instead with the image

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46339/discussion-between-romasz-and-mta)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to use an image distributed with your app (AppData) You need to use the `appdata:` schema. If this is the case, you need to change the path to this:

`appdata:EHkozMIXZ8w.png`

If you are trying to use an image in the IsolatedStorage, you need to use the `isostore:` schema and store your image in the Shared\ShellContent folder.

You can take a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2011/10/19/resetting-the-live-tile-in-windows-phone-7.aspx) about using images in the appdata folder.

You can take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206971%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) about using images in the isolated storage folder.